# What is the easiest way to detect if a list contains only empty arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, list

What is the easiest way to check a list of arrays to see if the arrays they contain are all empty?

For example, this is what the arrays look like and the following output is what I would expect:

```
a = [[],[]] ==> True
b = [["x"], ["y"], []] ==> False
```

Comment: `print(all(el == [] for el in b))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming that you know that the list only contains other lists (which do not themselves contain lists), this is one way:

```
>>> not any(a)
True
>>> not any(b)
False
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) :

```
print(not any(a))
print(not any(b))
```

output:

```
True
False
```

Answer (score 0):

This can work:

```
for i in a:
    if len(str(i))>0:
        print("With Something")
    else:
        print("empty")
```